# Error trying to run Random Forest Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

This is the code I am trying to run

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
r2 = model.score(X_test, Y_test)
r2
```

And this is the error I receive. It seems that this is due to infinities or NaN being present in my data set, however I dont know how to remove them.

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Before splitting into X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test do this to your dataframe.

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Comment: I tried this and it still gives me the same error, I also tried converting my values from float64 to float32 and it still gives me the same error. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Try adding more info about your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Numpy arrays but not Pandas dataframes then try filtering numpy arrays from NaN rows, by using next function like `X_test = remove_nans(X_test)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xCsMwDET3fIVGG9zQNFuhX2JMEdQlhlgRslPqpb/uKp2q5d0J3YlbXTaae0@ZN6lAe@YGWIB4eMQnSMzbK94JqRi01wF0JNZdCNATj7iu5qNMRU8MjhLLghxV/ejPwcFpstYBvlOB22HCwJKomv/uo0oEm/F@cvp81K1G/cXBHIK1tvcv)

```
import numpy as np
def remove_nans(a):
    return a[np.all(~np.isnan(a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1)), axis = -1)]
print(remove_nans(np.array([[1, np.nan], [2, 3]]))) # Example
```

Output:

```
[[2., 3.]]
```

If you have dataframe then do `df.values = remove_nans(df.values)`.